# FactoryGirl - define several factories in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I'm trying to save some time by defining 1 factory instead of 30.

Why is this not working?

(Assuming we have a class method called :wanted_attributes)

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'faker'

models = %w[Model1 Model2]

models.each do |model|
    factoryname = model.downcase + "_e"

    FactoryGirl.define do 
        factory factoryname.to_sym, :class => model do 
            model.constantize.wanted_attributes.each do |attribute|
                attribute Faker::Name.first_name
            end
        end         
    end
end
```

I'm getting the error:

> FactoryGirl::AttributeDefinitionError: Attribute already defined:
>   attribute

Comment: I don't think you need to call `constantize` if you are passing the actual class in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are looping through the wanted_attributes, you are always creating a single attribute named 'attribute'.  You need to use the send method to make sure you use the value of the attribute variable instead of the name 'attribute':

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'faker'

models = %w[Model1 Model2]

models.each do |model|
    factoryname = model.downcase + "_e"

    FactoryGirl.define do 
        factory factoryname.to_sym, :class => model do 
            model.constantize.wanted_attributes.each do |attribute|
                send(attribute.to_sym, Faker::Name.first_name) ##### Use send
            end
        end         
    end
end
```

Comment: I suggest you highlight the fact that you are calling `send`

Comment: Thanks. Short and to the point :) I read about it later, and figured that they are using method missing to achieve FactoryGirl DSL. Once we send (ask for) a method called attribute.to_sym, method missing is activated, then they create a method called attribute.to_sym that returns Faker::Name.first_name..